# Making new JTable from a selection of another JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I wrote the code below to make a new JTable when I make a selection on the current JTable:

```
makeTbale.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    int[] selectedCols = table.getSelectedColumns();
    Object[] newCols = new Object[selectedCols.length];
    TableModel model = table.getModel();
    int selectedRows = model.getRowCount();
    Object[][] output = new Object[selectedCols][selectedRows];
    for(int nCol = 0; nCol < selectedCols.length; nCol++) {
      for{int nRow = 0; nRow<selectedRows;nRow++) {
        output[nCol][nRow] = model.getValueAt(nRow, selectedCols[nCol]).toString();
        newCols[nCol] = table.getModel().getColumnName(selectedCols[nCol]);
      }
    }
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(output,newCols));
});
```

Now this is the data that I select:

```
Col2     |Col3     |Col5     |Col6     |Col7     |Col10
1/1/2017 |3.45     |1.2      |hello    |b1_133   |test
1/2/2017 |3.11     |4.9      |x        |b3_122   |you
1/3/2013 |2.98     |5.5      |ask      |c1_001   |foo
1/4/2012 |1.90     |2.1      |y        |v7_670   |hey
1/6/2000 |9.99     |7.77     |w        |c3_890   |fee
1/7/2012 |10.45    |8.75     |test     |u0_998   |faa
.
.
.
```

It goes down to 100 more rows.

This is the table that I get after running my code:

```
Col2     |Col3     |Col5     |Col6     |Col7     |Col10
1/1/2017 |1/2/2017 |1/3/2013 |1/4/2012 |1/6/2000 |1/7/2012
3.45     |3.11     |2.98     |1.90     |9.99     |10.45
1.2      |4.9      |5.5      |2.1      |7.77     |8.75
hello    |x        |ask      |y        |w        |test
.
.
.
```

You get the idea, the selected columns are now rows and the rows are columns and only 6 rows are being viewed (Equal to the number of columns?).

Where is the error in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table row/cols have been swapped, so you've mixed up your array indexes.

Change

```
 output[nCol][nRow] = model.getValueAt(nRow, selectedCols[nCol]).toString();
```

to

```
 output[nRow][nCol] = model.getValueAt(nRow, selectedCols[nCol]).toString();
```

and switch the indexes on this line:

```
Object[][] output = new Object[selectedCols][selectedRows];
```

Comment: That's what i thought! But when I do so, i get a runtime error saying array index is out of bounds: 6

Comment: You might also have your for loops the wrong way around, since you have more rows than columns, if you mix them up, then it will try and put more rows into the columns than you have column space

Comment: Try the for loop up to selectedCols.length - 1

Comment: Do you also need to switch indexes in Object[][] output = new Object[selectedCols][selectedRows];

Comment: Aha yes ! I forgot to do that lol, it worked perfectly, thanks! :)